# Open viewcontroller via siri

Tags: ios, swift, siri, swift2, sirikit

Is it possible to open a particular viewcontroller via Siri?

For example ,
I want to search for "open my profile in myApp" and go to "My Profile" viewcontroller.

I need this for all menu items shown in below image.

[image]

Comment: check this out: http://jamesonquave.com/blog/adding-siri-to-ios-10-apps-in-swift-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

SiriKit can be used for this purpose (as of iOS10):

- VoIP calling
- Messaging
- Payments
- Photos
- Workouts
- Ride booking
- Car commands
- CarPlay (automotive vendors only)
- Restaurant reservations (requires additional support from Apple)

It doesn't seems that what you want to do will fit into those spec.
What you can do is, with your app up and running, create voice commands using the `Speech` [framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech).